# How to trigger Glide to download images in scroll view by scrolling up and down

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide

So, I have an AsyncTask which loads an sql query and results will be shown in table layout. "extractArrayList" method extracts query results into array lists and 
"populateItemsTable" method populates table to show results.

```
public boolean extractArrayList(ArrayList<JSONObject> result_obj) {
    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < result_obj.size(); i++) {
            item_createDate.add(result_obj.get(i).getString("CreateDate"));
            item_name.add(result_obj.get(i).getString("Name"));
            item_unit.add(result_obj.get(i).getString("Unit"));
            item_textLable.add(result_obj.get(i).getString("TextLable"));
            item_topSale.add(result_obj.get(i).getString("TopSale"));
            item_Fee.add(result_obj.get(i).getString("Fee"));
            item_moreInfo.add(result_obj.get(i).getString("MoreInfo"));
            item_IfImageUploaded.add(result_obj.get(i).getString("IfImageUploaded"));
        }
        Collections.reverse(item_createDate);
        Collections.reverse(item_name);
        Collections.reverse(item_textLable);
        Collections.reverse(item_unit);
        Collections.reverse(item_Fee);
        Collections.reverse(item_IfImageUploaded);
        Collections.reverse(item_moreInfo);
        Collections.reverse(item_topSale);
        return true;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean populateItemsTable(){
    TableLayout items_table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.items_table);
    for (int i = 0; i < item_createDate.size(); i++) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View tr = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null, false);

        tr.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            }
        });

        tr.setOnGenericMotionListener(new View.OnGenericMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGenericMotion(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                return false;
            }
        });

        tr.setOnHoverListener(new View.OnHoverListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onHover(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                return false;
            }
        });

        tr.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {

            }
        });
        TextView item_nameTxt = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.item_nameTxt);
        TextView item_feeTxt = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.item_feeTxt);
        TextView item_textTxt = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.item_textTxt);
        ImageView item_imgView = (ImageView) tr.findViewById(R.id.item_imgView);
        final Button add_basket_btn = (Button) tr.findViewById(R.id.basket_btn);
        final Button more_info_btn = (Button) tr.findViewById(R.id.moreInfo_btn);

        item_nameTxt.setText(item_name.get(i).toString());

        Float item_fee_float = Float.parseFloat(item_Fee.get(i));
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) nf;
        item_feeTxt.setText("قیمت: " + df.format(item_fee_float) + " ریال / " + item_unit.get(i).toString());
        item_textTxt.setText(item_textLable.get(i).toString());

        if (item_IfImageUploaded.get(i).equals("Yes")) {
            String pic_url = item_createDate.get(i).toLowerCase().replaceAll("[-]", "");
            pic_url = item_createDate.get(i).toLowerCase().replaceAll("[:]", "");
            pic_url = pic_url.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[ ]", "");
            pic_url = pic_url.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[-]", "");
            pic_url = "http://www.coffeetaxi.ir/iteminfo/photo/" + pic_url + ".jpg";

            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(pic_url.toString())
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(item_imgView);
        } else {
            item_imgView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.no_image);
        }

        add_basket_btn.setTag(i);
        add_basket_btn.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.basket_btn);
        add_basket_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Integer code;
                code = Integer.parseInt(add_basket_btn.getTag().toString());
                askForQTY(itemsActivity.this, code, item_name.get(code), "مقدار/تعداد مورد نظر را وارد نمایید", false);
            }
        });

        more_info_btn.setTag(i);
        more_info_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                moreInfoCall = Integer.parseInt(more_info_btn.getTag().toString());
                itemsActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(itemsActivity.this, MoreinfoActivity.class));
            }
        });

        if (item_moreInfo.get(i).equals("none")) {

            more_info_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        } else {

        }
        items_table.addView(tr);
    }

    return true;
}
```

onPostExecute method of AsyncTask calls two above methods respectivly.
This code works fine but one:
All images of results going to be downloaded immediately and it causes high memory allocation.
What I want is to make changes to above code (open to lots of changes ;)) to make Glide load images when scrolling to specific item.(some thing like what Instagram app does!)
here is main activity XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/items_table"
        android:scrollIndicators="left"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:showDividers="middle"></TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and table row layout in case:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/img_rel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<ImageView
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="160dp"
    android:maxWidth="160dp"
    android:id="@+id/item_imgView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/desc_rel"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/item_nameTxt"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/basket_btn"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:id="@+id/item_feeTxt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/basket_btn"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_nameTxt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:id="@+id/item_textTxt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/basket_btn"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_feeTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/basket_btn"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@mipmap/basket_btn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_textTxt"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/moreInfo_btn"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/more_info"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_textTxt"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/basket_btn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You request Glide to download image immediately when layout is inflated, and it's not OK.

In my opinion, you should use ListView or RecycleView, instead of TableLayout. Glide should download image only when binding view holder.